# VirtualBox kernel issue. 3.19.0-25-generic

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I am attempting to setup virtualbox on a new Ubuntu install and have been running into issues. I have uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times and issues continue. I tried removing autocleaning out the current kernels and that didn't help.

Here is the install record and you can see the error:

http://pastebin.com/p3sqADhD

```
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.19.0-25-generic
Building initial module for 3.19.0-25-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-25-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/make.log for more information.
```

And below is the make.log:

http://pastebin.com/axbw9rni

I am at a loss as to what's going on as I have done this before without issues. I have used sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: You could just try installing it from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: I've done that successfully with multiple versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I am running 14.04. I tried from software center and had same problem.

Comment: Try upgrading to 15.04

Comment: That did not help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon that Virtual Box has issues on building for newer kernel releases. The developers do a great job in fixing those issues but they need some time to do so.

The issues with builing for kernels > 3.19 should be fixed in Virtual Box versions > 4.3.22, and issues with kernel 4.0 were fixed in 4.3.24, resp. 4.3.26 (see [changelog for Virtual Box 4.3](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-4.3)).

Therefore whenever we are faced with building on any newer kernel we should upgrade Virtual Box to the newest stable release.

If a bug was still not fixed we should [report this to the developers](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker).