# Failed install VirtualBox on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualbox

I am experiencing problems installing  Virtual Box on Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.19.0-26 x86_64:

```
sudo apt-cache policy virtualbox

sudo apt-get install virtualbox

Setting up virtualbox (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules    [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules 
 * No suitable module for running kernel found


Building initial module for 3.19.0-26-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/make.log for more information.
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules       [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                                                                                                              * No suitable module for running kernel found [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.



$ grep -i error /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/make.log
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.c:186:48: error: macro "alloc_netdev" requires 4 arguments, but only 3 given
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.c:184:15: error: ‘alloc_netdev’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp/linux/VBoxNetAdp-linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build/vboxnetadp] Error 2
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/4.3.10/build] Error 2


ls -l /etc/init.d/vboxdrv 
ls: cannot access /etc/init.d/vboxdrv: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone advise how to proceed?

Comment: Check if http://askubuntu.com/questions/666026/virtualbox-5-0-installation-has-broken-virtualbox-packages-on-kubuntu-15-04/666039#666039 which is for 15.04 works for you.

Comment: @KarlRichter, Spot on - that link you posted worked for me.  I did have to specify sudo apt-get install dkms virtualbox-5.0 instead of just ¨virtualbox-5¨, but yes, Iḿ now able to run virtual box 5.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/660166/virtualbox-kernel-issue-3-19-0-25-generic